# How do you stream files from a tar.zstd archive in Python

Tags: python, archive, zstandard

I've got a few tar.zst files which are 120 GB or so consisting of of mostly text files.
Is there a way to open a tar.zst in streaming way/mode so that it doesn't (completely) decompress the archive?
I tried tarfile, unfortunately it doesn't support zstd.

Comment: You may take a look at https://python-zstandard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decompressor.html and combine it with tarfile.